# How do I inject a different dependency mock into a service partway through the test suite for that service?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

When testing an Angular service (with its own dependencies), I oftentimes find myself stuck at testing both the happy path and the sad path within the test suite.

What I mean is I have this service:

```js
export class MyService {
  constructor(private MyClient) {}

  public doIt() {
    return this.myClient.doTheThing().pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        // error handling logic
      }),
      // process the response
    )
  }
}
```

And now I would like to test `MyService#doIt` when `MyClient#doTheThing` runs successfully and returns an observable of the response/result for that request, but also when `MyClient#doTheThing` fails and errors (since I have some logic in the `catchError` to be tested).

Testing the happy path is easy enough:

```js
// MyClientMock is a mock implementation of MyClient that returns a canned result 
// for instance so that I can test against these values when running the tests.

describe(MyService, () => {
  let service: MyService

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService,
        { provide: MyClient, useClass: MyClientMock }
      ],
    })
    service = TestBed.inject(MyService)
  })

  it('does the thing', (done) => {
    service.doIt().subscribe(result => {
      expect(result).toEqual('something')
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

But how do I test the sad path, when `MyClient` throws an error instead, and ensure the logic in `catchError` does what I expect it to?

I thought about creating another `MyClientMock` and name it, say, `MyClientErrorMock` which will throw. But then I can't inject it because it's all been already setup at the beginning of the test and it would interfere with other test cases.

What's a good pattern to use in this case to test what happens when the dependency errors or succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) over Karma.

When you need to recreate a complex behavior of a mock function such that multiple function calls produce different results, use the mockImplementationOnce method:

```
const myMockFn = jest
  .fn()
  .mockImplementationOnce(cb => cb(null, true))
  .mockImplementationOnce(cb => cb(null, false));

myMockFn((err, val) => console.log(val));
// > true

myMockFn((err, val) => console.log(val));
// > false
```

Here is another example of a mock, which produces a result based on conditional argument:

```
import { when } from 'jest-when';

const fn = jest.fn();
when(fn).calledWith(1).mockReturnValue('hello world!');

const result = fn(1);
expect(result).toEqual('hello world!');
```

I would say the biggest advantage of Jest over Karma is its non-cryptic, straight-forward error messages which lets you determine the root cause of test failures at a glance.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!